# Remove MKMapView Overlay on Button Push

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I have a `MKMapView` with a `MKOverlay` over it showing the location history of the user. On a button press, how can I discard this overlay and remove it from view?

I have tried `[map removeOverlay:overlay];` but that doesn't work - it still shows.

Comment: How is the `overlay` variable set or obtained?  If you log `map.overlays.count` before and after the remove, what does it show?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will work

```
NSArray *pointsArray = [mapView overlays];

[mapView removeOverlays:pointsArray];
```

Comment: For swift 4 
let pointsArray:Array = self.mapView.overlays
self.mapView.removeOverlays(pointsArray)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add that, for my iPad application, I needed to add an extra line to the solution shown above:

```
  NSArray *pointsArray = [self.mapView overlays];
  [self.mapView removeOverlays:pointsArray];

  self.mapOverlayView = nil;
```

Without setting mapOverlayView to nil, the "removeOverlays" call didn't seem to do much (?)

Comment: But I don't have mapOverLayView property in my code. How to remove previous lay?